# Yii createUrl using current url as base (behavior differs among servers)

Tags: php, yii, nginx

Application hosted on `www.domain.com`

```
$this->createUrl( '/admin' );
```

User clicks admin link and is taken to `www.domain.com/admin`

```
$this->createUrl( '/products' );
```

User clicks products link and is taken to `www.domain.com/admin/products` instead of the expected `www.domain.com/products`

Strangely, on the staging server, when clicking on products, the user is taken to the expected `www.domain.com/products` url but when the code is pushed to production, we start seeing this issue.

I've asked my client to provide PHP version differences, so in the meantime, if someone knows what the issue might be here, please enlighten me.

The actions simply get data from model and render view - no redirections, etc

**Layout code**

```
<?php if ( ! Yii::app()->user->isGuest ): ?>
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul class="l_tinynav1">

        <li<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->id === 'admin' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl( '/admin' ); ?>">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->id === 'products' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl( '/products' ); ?>">Products</a>
        </li>

        <li<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->id === 'services' || Yii::app()->controller->id === 'faq' ? '     class="active"' : ''; ?>>
            <a href="#">Content</a>
            <ul style="display: block;">
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl( '/services' ); ?>">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl( '/faq' ); ?>">FAQs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl( '/admin/logout' ); ?>">Logout</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note**

The servers use nginx proxy_pass directive to setup a reverse proxy

So I have to define requests['hostInfo'] in the config file like this:

```
'components' => array
(
    'request'=>array
(
        'hostInfo'=>'http://www.domain.com'
),
```

Might be related

**UPDATE**

After some debugging, I found something interesting. If I am on the `/products/add` page, `createUrl` will generate the right link for `/admin`. But if I am on the `/admin` page, `createUrl` will generate the incorrect link for `/products/add`. Following some further investigation, I found the these `$_SERVER` properties to be different.

*When I'm on `/admin`*

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /admin/index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /admin/index.php
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /admin/index.php
```

*When I'm on `/products/add`*

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /products/add
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
```

It looks like it's only an issue on first-level routes, `/route` will be an issue, but `/route/action` will not.

**[nginx config](http://pastebin.com/tZCgHWxD)**

PHP Version: 5.3.27
OS: Ubuntu 12

**UPDATE**

Did a diff of $_SERVER headers between staging and production for `/admin` route

*Staging*

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /admin/
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.0.14
```

*Production*

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /admin/index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /admin/index.php
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /admin/index.php
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.4.2
```

Comment: Does they belong to same controller? Are you working within module?

Comment: Its part of the layout code - these links are in the menu. No modules are being used.

Comment: please add some code regarding actions and your view. so it may be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by forcing the `baseUrl`

```
'request'=>array
(
    'hostInfo'=>'http://www.domain.com',
    'baseUrl'=>'http://www.domain.com'
)
```

Though I hope someone could provide an explanatory answer.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use a global function like this:

```
function url($route,$params=array(),$ampersand='&'){
    return Yii::app()->createUrl($route,$params,$ampersand);
}
```

Now, you can use url( '/admin' ):

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul class="l_tinynav1">
    <li<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->id === 'admin' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo url( '/admin' ); ?>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->id === 'products' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo url( '/products' ); ?>">Products</a>
    </li>
    ...
    <li><a href="<?php echo url( '/admin/logout' ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

In the views, you could use url($this->id.'/index'):

```
<div class="span2 btn-toolbar">
    <?php echo CHtml::link('Listado',url($this->id.'/index'),array('class'=>'btn')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it, what does your function do? It's just a shorthand for the createUrl function, correct?

Comment: Perhaps it is, but why does it belong here?